# Number of NFT tokens to mint

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, contract-design, nft

I see that many smart contracts for minting NFT tokens use a function that accepts the number of tokens to be minted, here are examples:

```
function adopt(uint256 num) public payable
function mintAlien(uint numberOfTokens) public payable
function mintHobo(uint256 count) external payable nonReentrant
function buyBeasts(uint numberOfTokens) external payable
function mintApe(uint numberOfTokens) public payable
```

Why pass this number if you can count it like this:

```
uint numberOfTokens = msg.value / tokenPrice;
```

Answer (score 0):

All these functions are using unsigned integer, uint, So the value can only be positive. In the other hand,

```
msg.value / tokenPrice
```

There are more chances that your value will be decimals represented in WEI but it could never be less than 0. If for a reason the result is negative. your code will revert with underflow error. Because a uint can't be negative.

So when you check for an uint you are saving your self some extra work because a negative value would not be considered.

```
0 * price = 0
```

There are no decimals in solidity.

So for example a very small amount divided by a bigger amount tends to break thing in solidity.

This is why you often see

```
smallAmount * 1e12 / biggerAmount;
```

Now you kind of handle decimals in a way.

But why make things harder than they are.

How many tokens you want to buy?

42!

Keep it simple right!

Comment: If tokenPrice is a uint, then there is no chance of getting a negative value.
(For example: uint tokenPrice = 2;)
Then, when paying for 5 WEI, we will receive an integer number of tokens = 2.
But there is a chance that when the function is called, the number of tokens is 1 and the sum of 5 WEI will be transferred. Then we get only 1 tokens or an error.

Comment: Maybe just check for the tokens available. Buy them and return the balance?

Comment: Or, in my version, just count the number of tokens, mint them and return the rest of the money. How is it worse?